# d3 .attr('fill', "rgba(0,0,0,0.18") works; calling a function does not

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some D3 code that works fine. It includes a call like this to fill an area with grey:

```
...
.attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,.18)")
...
```

However, if I change that line to the following (where fillSmoke() returns the same string `"rgba(0,0,0,.18)"`), the chart is filled with black, not the desired grey.

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {fillSmoke(d,i)})

... and later ...

fillSmoke = (d, i) => {
    return "rgba(0,0,0,0.18)"
  }
```

I have a sense that D3 must be parsing `"rgba(0,0,0,.18)"` in the first case, but not the second. What can I do to return the desired grey value from fillSmoke()? Thanks.

**Solution:** Change the function body to include `return` (e.g., `{return fillSmoke(d,i)}` Thanks!

Comment: You're missing `return`...

Comment: D'oh! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the `.attr` method can be a function, but it must return the color value you want to use. Right now your function just calls fillSmoke, but returns no value. Fix this by changing the line to:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return fillSmoke(d,i); })
```

The return statement is needed to return the value -- this works so long as fillSmoke is returning the color value you want. Alternatively, this may work too:

```
.attr("fill", fillSmoke)
```

See [more](https://www.d3indepth.com/datajoins)

Comment: *"Right now your function just calls fillSmoke, but returns no value"*... this is incorrect, all functions in JS return a value. In this case, it is `undefined`.

Comment: As several posters point out, I need to add `return` to the function body... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake - the function should have been defined to *return* the fillSmoke() results, like this:

`function(d, i) {return fillSmoke(d,i)}`

Thanks, all.